# How to match value in database in csv file?

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to compare value from csv files and database.

I create a dictionary where I put the name of the city as key and the zipcode as value.

So when I'm comparing the name of the city from my database and look into my csv files. The matches has not been done.

```
                for row in town_reader:
                    if row['_zipcode'] in (None,""):
                        zipcode = self.get_zip_from_adr(
                            row['Formatted / parsed address field used to retrieve Geolocator'])
                        row['_zipcode'] = zipcode
                        if row['_zipcode'] in (None, ""):
                            for k in dictionary.items():
                                if row['_town / _city'] == k:
                                    row['_zipcode'] = dictionary[k]
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imagesofcode (did not dv, but please share code fragments, not *images* of code fragments).

Comment: We're missing a lot of information here.

Answer (score 1):

`dictionary.items()` will return tuples of `(city name, zip code)`, while `row['_town / _city']` will be only the city name so there will never be equality.

You want to use `dictionary.keys()` to compare the keys (city name).

```
                for row in town_reader:
                    if row['_zipcode'] in (None,""):
                        zipcode = self.get_zip_from_adr(
                            row['Formatted / parsed address field used to retrieve Geolocator'])
                        row['_zipcode'] = zipcode
                        if row['_zipcode'] in (None, ""):
                            for k in dictionary.keys(): ### <--- HERE
                                if row['_town / _city'] == k:
                                    row['_zipcode'] = dictionary[k]
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```